# function not returning lowest grade of students to main

Tags: c++

I want to do a program to calculate average of students grades while dropping lowest score. 
To do so I created 3 functions for average of scores, gettting scores from user input and lowest score.
However, in the main function I am not getting the lowest value returned rather I only get the initial value.
Here is the code, thanks.
I am only posting the main parts of the question, if you want the rest of the code I will edit the question.

```
int main() {
    int students = 0;
    int avg = 0.0f;
    int total = 0;
    int i = 0;
    float lowest = 0;
    int sumofhigh = 0;
    cout << "================Calculating average of grades while dropping lowest grade============\n \n";
    int score[25];

    getscores(score, total, i);
    cout << "\n";
    lowest =  lowgrade(score, students);
    cout << "The lowest score is: " << lowest << " ";


}

int lowgrade(int score[], int numberstudent) {
    int low = score[0];
    for (int i = 0; i <= numberstudent ; ++i) {
        if (score[i]<low) 
            low = score[i];

    }
    return low;
}
void getscores(int score[], int &total, int i) {
    int student = 0; total = 0;  i = 0;;
    cout << "Please enter the number of students: "; cin >> student;
    while (student < 0) {
        cout << "Students can't be negative can they? enter again: "; cin >> student;
    }

    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Now enter the grades for each of the students!: \n";
    for ( i = 0; i < student; ++i) {
        cout << "Enter grades for student " << i + 1 << " "; cin >> score[i];
        while (score[i] < 0 || score[i]>100) {
            cout << "Students can't get above hundred or have negative grades, enter again: "; cin >> score[i];
        }

        total += score[i];
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "The total sum of grades is: " << total << " ";
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= numberstudent ; ++i) {` is an off by 1 bug. The condition should be `i < numberstudent`

Comment: `getscores(score, total, i);` does getscores modify `i` meaning is the last parameter passed by reference?

Comment: Is `students` ever set to a value that isn't 0? According to the code you posted it isn't

Comment: `i <= numberstudent`: if `numberstudent` is the size of array, you should use non-inclusive range: `i < numberstudent`.

Comment: Ok bare with me here I will reply to each one

Comment: @UnholySheep is correct did you mean to have `getscores(score, total, i);` or `getscores(score, total, students);`

Comment: @drescherjm Fixed.

Comment: @drescherjm No it does not modify i so a pass by reference is uneeded.

Comment: `students` is always 0. You never update this.

Comment: ***No it does not modify i so a pass by reference is uneeded.*** Then how do you plan on updating the count of students?

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov Sir, students changes in the getscores function I take the number of students and then i enter grades based on that number.

Comment: No it does not. `students` is a local variable in `main()` it's inaccessible in `getscores`

Comment: @drescherjm Sir, if you do not mind, I can edit the question to make it more clear if you wish.

Comment: @JohnnyJoestar, then provide the whole snippet. In your code `students` is never changed.

Comment: @drescherjm Sir, I believe it does because I get the sum of the grades as well, it is implemented in the getscores() function

Comment: It's not about editing your question. This is your second bug with the code.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov I will provide the whole code as requested, please hold on while I edit the question.

Comment: @drescherjm Sir, the question at first asks for a fixed number of students (5 to be precise) but I decided to do it for a user input value of students.

Comment: If you declare a second variable name `students` inside `getscores()` that is a separate variable having nothing to do with the variable of the same name in `main()`

Comment: I fully understand the task you  are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213453/discussion-between-drescherjm-and-johnny-joestar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling for the function lowgrade()
from main and sending students, which is set to 0. The variable numberstudent in the function will be zero. It never reaches inside the for loop and therefore takes only the first argument.

edit: when you declare on student variable inside getscores function, it's a local variable. Inside a function, you can not update students value this way. When you finish getscores(), you filled score array but students is still 0

Comment: Sir, do you think calling it as reference variable will fix the issue?

Comment: @JohnnyJoestar if you send students to getscores() as an argument by reference, then yes. Do this instead of declare a new variable

Comment: Ok so I have done that, but now I get a value of infinity.

Comment: Try to debug by looking on the value of students right after finishing getscores(). Does it hold the right amount of students?

Comment: Yes it does, I enter 5 students and it gives out 5 students.

Comment: What about in `main()`

Comment: Sir, I have done this in `main` as well, and I also get 5 (or any other number I enter). The number 5 prints out, I did mention that I get the total sum of grades actually.

Comment: I then think the code changed too much from what we see to give any advice. You probably want to call this question done / accept this answer. And ask a new question with the new problem and updated code. It's too difficult to follow.

Comment: Hello sir, the issue has been fixed and my code works fine, thank you all to whoever contributed.